# Nesing Pagemodel in ABP.io MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor-pages, abp

I've got a page model that has an abp-tabs defined as

```
}
<abp-dynamic-form abp-model="Item" asp-page="/Anagrafiche/Clienti/EditModal">
    <abp-modal size="Large">
        <abp-modal-header title="@L["Update"].Value"></abp-modal-header>
        <abp-modal-body>
            <abp-tabs>
                <abp-tab title="Generale">
                    <abp-form-content />
                    

                </abp-tab>
                <abp-tab title="Scontistiche">
                    @{
                        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_Scontistiche");
                    }
                </abp-tab>
                <abp-tab title="Clienti con stesso comune">

                
                </abp-tab>
                <abp-tab title="Clienti con stessa provincia">
                    Clienti con stessa provincia
                </abp-tab>
            </abp-tabs>
        </abp-modal-body>
        <abp-modal-footer buttons="@(AbpModalButtons.Cancel|AbpModalButtons.Save)"></abp-modal-footer>
    </abp-modal>
</abp-dynamic-form>
```

I've defined the _Scontistiche.cshtml as

```
 public class _ScontisticheModel : xxxPageModel
    {
        public _ScontisticheModel()
        {
            
        }
        public void OnGet()
        {
        }
    }
```

But when I run it I got

*System.InvalidOperationException: 'The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'xxx.Web.Pages.Anagrafiche.Clienti.EditModalModel', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'xxx.Web.Pages.Anagrafiche.Clienti._ScontisticheModel'.'*

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Partial pages should not have a PageModel class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is saying you are passing the wrong model to your partialview. Looking at the code, this error is indeed correct. The following line is causing the issue.

```
@{
    await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_Scontistiche");
 }
```

By default the model of your parent page will be sent to the partial view, unless you define a different model. You can do this by passing a `_ScontisticheModel` model like so.

```
@{
   await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_Scontistiche", Item);
}
```

Considering `Item` is the correct model you are referring to. If you don't have a model, you can also pass a new class like so:

```
await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_Scontistiche", new _ScontisticheModel());
```

Comment: excuse me , but _ScontisticheModel you say I need to pass, isn't the name of the Page? It's not a model as normally intended

Comment: Your error says it expects a model of type `_ScontisticheModel`. You are feeding it a `EditModalModel`

Comment: Your parent has a certain model, but your partial view `_Scontistiche` has a `_ScontisticheModel`.